# Save as without creating a new file?

Tags: windows, save-as

Is there a way in Windows to *save* an existing file (after editing it) *as* without ending up with two files, of which the old one I'll have to manually look up in file explorer and delete it?

So essentially rename and save it in one go or save it normally as a new file and simultaneously delete the old file with the old name?

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Comment: How would this be different from saving "normally" and renaming the file?

Answer (score 2):

In the Save As dialog, you would need to delete the existing file before
saving, by right-click on the old file that is displayed in the list
and selecting "Delete".

There is a little gotcha here, in that the displayed file-name
will change to the one that you right-clicked. If you wish to conserve
the name, you would need to copy it before deleting, then paste it
back in.

Comment: It's a work-around, but a pretty good one. I was not aware that an open file could be deleted, but I tried and you're right, this works, so I accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: In the meantime I realized that this doesn't work e.g. in MS Excel. In another app it worked, but overall it seems not to be a universal solution, unfortunately. Anyway, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Just tried it in Excel, what is the problem?

Comment: In fact, this is a Windows dialog, not an invention of Excel, so it has to work no matter which program it's called from.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. With my slightly older, installed Excel-version I get an error that I can't delete a file that's currently open. I was surprised that this approach worked with other apps at all, because strictly speaking this error message makes sense.

Comment: But don't get me wrong, I upvoted your answer because it's a nice workaround in apps where it does work.

Comment: How come the file is open?

Answer (score 0):

Since not all apps allow to delete a currently open file in the *Save as*-dialogue, I came up with the idea to just `Ctrl+C` the file in the same dialogue (puts its full path into the clipboard) and — after saving it under a different name — delete the old one with help of a little **AutoHotkey**-script:

```
+^d::   ; Shift + Ctrl + D (but you can define your own hotkey)
    FileDelete, %clipboard%
    if ErrorLevel
        MsgBox, 'FileDelete' failed — was there no (full) file-path in the ClipBoard?
Return
```